# Not able to pass ajax post request to register controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass the ajax post request to register controller in asp.net mvc, but it's throwing an error.

```
$('#btnRegister').click(function () {
                var model = new Object();
                model.Email = $('#signup_email').val();
                model.Password = $('#signup_password').val();
                model.ConfirmPassword = $('#signup_confirm_password').val();
                $.ajax({

                    url: 'api/Account/Register',
                    method: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    success: function () {

                        $('#successmodal').modal();
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');

                    }
                });


            });

        });
```

Below is by default mvc register controller

```
// POST api/Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Modal is showing invalid model object passed.[image]

Comment: @Taplar but it was in built controller with template.. i have not modified it

Comment: yes..it because it works if I create a mvc template and register user using razor page. Then it should work with jquery also..

Comment: .net is unable to serialize the data your passing to the controller from ajax. Can you capture the request and show the json body youre sending? If you set a breakpoint in the `Register` action, I'm pretty sure you'll see all of your model properties are the defaults (null for string, etc) and that's why its kicking out validation errors for required fields, etc. It'd probably be helpful if you posted the `RegisterBindingModel` model.

Comment: @GregH is right, you should also post your `RegisterBindingModel`.  It is likely that the object you're sending in the Ajax request doesn't match up with what's in `RegisterBindingModel` and therefore can't deserialize properly.